# SEO 301 redirectmatch when you already have a root redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo, http-status-code-301

On the root or my client's server (www.thesite.com), among a bunch of folders and directories, lies an installation of an expressionEngine site which works.

The client asked me to build a new website with wordpress instead. Which i did. So now there is a new folder on the root of "www.thesite.com" named "wordpress_root" (www.thesite.com/wordpress_root). Inside, the whole of of a wordpress directory. And since i need to bypass the old expressionEngine site without deleting it altogether, i  went to "settings/general" in the wordpress admin panel and set the "site address URL" to "www.thesite.com" and fixed an .htaccess and index.php files in the root folder, right in "www.thesite.com", adding .bak to the original  expressionEngine .htaccess and index.php files. 
All Good.

But now, i want to make sure not to loose any SEO juice from the old site. The new urls are at 80% the exact same as the old urls. But now, the root of the new site is not on the root of the server, it is in the "wordpress_root" directory.

So my question is this: How to use the .htaccess 301 redirectMatch command when the webroot of my wordpress site is already redirected to "www.thesite.com/wordpress_root? Will there be a conflict between the native wordpress redirection to its root directory and the SEO overall 301 redirections?

Thanks!

Hum, i hope i am clear enough...

Answer (score 0):

Matchi it with:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /wordpress_root/
```

Comment: Even if there is already this in the .htaccess file that lies in the root dir of the server:

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress_root/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress_root/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

I can just add the RedirectMatch line to that .htaccess file without causing any conflict?